# Element by Element comparison in Lua

Tags: lua, dsl, lua-table, metalua

I'm trying to find a way to do element-by-element comparison in Lua using the standard `<` operator. For example, here's what I'd like to do:

```
a = {5, 7, 10}
b = {6, 4, 15}
c = a < b -- should return {true, false, true}
```

I already have code working for addition (and subtraction, multiplication, etc). My issue is that Lua forces the result of a comparison to a boolean. I don't want a boolean, I want a table as the result of the comparison.

Here is my code so far, with addition working, but less-than comparison not working:

```
m = {}
m['__add'] = function (a, b)
    -- Add two tables together
    -- Works fine
    c = {}
    for i = 1, #a do
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i]
    end
    return c
end
m['__lt'] = function (a, b)
    -- Should do a less-than operator on each element
    -- Doesn't work, Lua forces result to boolean
    c = {}
    for i = 1, #a do
        c[i] = a[i] < b[i]
    end
    return c
end


a = {5, 7, 10}
b = {6, 4, 15}

setmetatable(a, m)

c = a + b -- Expecting {11, 11, 25}
print(c[1], c[2], c[3]) -- Works great!

c = a < b -- Expecting {true, false, true}
print(c[1], c[2], c[3]) -- Error, lua makes c into boolean
```

The Lua programming manual says that the result of the `__lt` metamethod call is always converted to a boolean. My question is, how can I work around that? I heard that Lua is good for DSL, and I really need the syntax to work here. I think it should be possible using MetaLua, but I'm not really sure where to start.

A coworker suggested that I just use `<<` instead with the `__shl` metamethod. I tried it and it works, but I really want to use `<` for less than, rather than a hack using the wrong symbol.

Thanks!

Comment: why do you need it as an operator? can't you just use a normal function?

Comment: @Piglet I'm making a DSL. I want to be able to do something like `a*(b+5)/c<d` where `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are all vectors (arrays). Rewriting that as prefix function calls is very verbose: `less_than(divide(multiply(a, add(b, 5),c),d)`. I can't ask my users to write that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have two choices to make this work with your syntax:

**Option 1: Patch the Lua core.**

This is probably going to be very difficult, and it'll be a maintenance nightmare in the future. The biggest issue is that Lua assumes on a very low level that the comparison operators `<`, `>`, `==`, `~=` return a bool value.

The byte-code that Lua generates actually does a jump on any comparison. For example, something like `c = 4 < 5` gets compiled to byte-code that looks much more like `if (4 < 5) then c = true else c = false end`.

You can see what the byte-code looks like with `luac -l file.lua`. If you compare the byte-code of `c=4<5` with `c=4+5` you'll see what I mean. The addition code is shorter and simpler. Lua assumes you'll do branching with comparisons, not assignment.

**Option 2: Parse your code, change it, and run that**

This is what I think you should do. It would be very hard, expect most of the work is already done for you (using something like [LuaMinify](https://github.com/stravant/LuaMinify)).

First of all, write a function you can use for comparisons of anything. The idea here is to do your special comparison if it's a table, but fall back on using `<` for everything else.

```
my_less = function(a, b)
   if (type(a) == 'table') then
     c = {}
     for i = 1, #a do
       c[i] = a[i] < b[i]
     end
     return c
    else
      return a < b
    end
end
```

Now all we need to do is replace every less than operator `a<b` with `my_less(a,b)`.

Let's use the parser from [LuaMinify](https://github.com/stravant/LuaMinify). We'll call it with the following code:

```
local parse = require('ParseLua').ParseLua
local ident = require('FormatIdentity')

local code = "c=a*b<c+d"
local ret, ast = parse(code)
local _, f = ident(ast)
print(f)
```

All this will do is parse the code into a syntax tree, and then spit it back out again. We'll change `FormatIdentity.lua` to make it do the substitution. Replace the section near line 138 with the following code:

```
    elseif expr.AstType == 'BinopExpr' then --line 138
        if (expr.Op == '<') then
            tok_it = tok_it + 1
            out:appendStr('my_less(')
            formatExpr(expr.Lhs)
            out:appendStr(',')
            formatExpr(expr.Rhs)
            out:appendStr(')')
        else
            formatExpr(expr.Lhs)
            appendStr( expr.Op )
            formatExpr(expr.Rhs)
        end
```

That's all there is to it. It will replace something like `c=a*b<c+d` with `my_less(a*b,c+d)`. Just shove all your code through at runtime.

Comment: Thanks! I will give your code a try and see how it works. I like the idea since it leaves me with the syntax I want, which is very important.

Answer (score 3):

Comparisons in Lua return a boolean value.

There is nothing you can do about it short of changing the core of Lua.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that in the manual. I guess I'm hoping I can preparse the code or something. Can I do it with MetaLua?

Comment: Any advice on where to start with patching the Lua. It looks like the comparison operators don't return anything internally, they are all interpreted as jumps. Even in the case of `a = 1 < 2` Lua uses a conditional jump to assign either `true` or `false` to a.

Comment: @jenny, exactly. It's not straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Can you put up with a bit verbose `v()`-notation:
`v(a < b)` instead of `a < b` ?

```
local vec_mt = {}

local operations = {
   copy     = function (a, b) return a     end,
   lt       = function (a, b) return a < b end,
   add      = function (a, b) return a + b end,
   tostring = tostring,
}

local function create_vector_instance(operand1, operation, operand2)
   local func, vec = operations[operation], {}
   for k, elem1 in ipairs(operand1) do
      local elem2 = operand2 and operand2[k]
      vec[k] = func(elem1, elem2)
   end
   return setmetatable(vec, vec_mt)
end

local saved_result

function v(...)  -- constructor for class "vector"
   local result = ...
   local tp = type(result)
   if tp == 'boolean' and saved_result then
      result, saved_result = saved_result
   elseif tp ~= 'table' then
      result = create_vector_instance({...}, 'copy')
   end
   return result
end

function vec_mt.__add(v1, v2)
   return create_vector_instance(v1, 'add', v2)
end

function vec_mt.__lt(v1, v2)
   saved_result = create_vector_instance(v1, 'lt', v2)
end

function vec_mt.__tostring(vec)
   return 
      'Vector ('
      ..table.concat(create_vector_instance(vec, 'tostring'), ', ')
      ..')'
end
```

**Usage:**

```
a = v(5, 7, 10); print(a)
b = v(6, 4, 15); print(b)

c =   a + b ; print(c)  -- result is v(11, 11, 25)
c = v(a + b); print(c)  -- result is v(11, 11, 25)
c = v(a < b); print(c)  -- result is v(true, false, true)
```

Comment: I just wanted to say that your idea is brilliant. This is not something I would have been able to come up with. Very creative! I'm not sure I can use it though. I'm making a DSL, and I think this sort of syntax will confuse people, for example someone will try: `c = v((a < b) == false)` and it falls apart.

Comment: What does `(a < b) == false` mean in your DSL?  You are comparing a vector with a boolean.

Comment: It would do an element-by-element comparison of each item with false, e.g. `{false, true, false} == false` would return `{true, false, true}`. Again though, I have no problem doing the calculation, just need help making the syntax acceptable.

Comment: To implement your own equality such as `vector == boolean` you will have to define special values (objects) `TRUE` and `FALSE` because it is unable to use `__eq` metamethod for comparing two different types.  You can use square-bracketed syntax for operations: `v[a < b]`, `v[a + b]`.  Then mistakenly written `v[[a < b] == FALSE]` will generate syntax error.  And you will be able to detect errors like this: `(a < b) == FALSE` too.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, there is no straight-forward solution to this.  However, with the use of a generic Python-like zip() function, such as the one shown below, you can simplify the problem, like so:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Python-like zip() iterator
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function zip(...)
  local arrays, ans = {...}, {}
  local index = 0
  return
    function()
      index = index + 1
      for i,t in ipairs(arrays) do
        if type(t) == 'function' then ans[i] = t() else ans[i] = t[index] end
        if ans[i] == nil then return end
      end
      return table.unpack(ans)
    end
end

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

a = {5, 7, 10}
b = {6, 4, 15}
c = {}

for a,b in zip(a,b) do
  c[#c+1] = a < b -- should return {true, false, true}
end

-- display answer
for _,v in ipairs(c) do print(v) end
```